# SQL: conditional count statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL and I have a SQL database with two columns, which in combination are unique (but their individual values are not): `songID` and `artistID`. Each song is recorded by different artists and each artist recorded different songs (see code below). I now want to extract information on who cooperated with whom.

I have tried

```
SELECT songID, COUNT(songID) FROM mytable
GROUP BY artist ID;
```

but this doesn't quite get me the results I want.

Consider this sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE "mytable" ("songID" int, "artistID" int);
INSERT INTO mytable ('songID', 'artistID') VALUES (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103), (2, 102), (2, 103), (3, 101), (3, 104);
```

The desired outcome is obtained logically by looking at song ID, e.g.: `songID` = 1: `artistID`s = `{101, 102, 103}`, so artist `101` has one common song with artist `102` and one with artist `103`, and artist `102` additionally has one common song with artist `103`. (Repeat for every `songID`). The desired result thus looks something like this:

```
"artist combinations"  "count"
"101 & 102"              1
"101 & 103"              1
"101 & 104"              1
"102 & 103"              2
"102 & 104"              0
"103 & 104"              0
```

Ideally, I would then sort this by `count`. Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You're probably going to need a self-join on `songID`.

Comment: What kind of SQL database is troubling you?  MySql? MS Sql Server? Oracle DB? Postgresql? SqLite?  And what version?  (`select @@version` works on some).

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQLite version 3.8.2.

Comment: What about having 3 artists working together? You could try to use a pivot to show the cooperations for 1 artist with each of the others. Then you LOOP this for all artists and feed the result into another table... (don't now if SQLite supports pivot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the results you need without the cases where there is not a common song between artists:

```
select  
  min(t.artistid, tt.artistid) || ' & ' || 
  max(t.artistid, tt.artistid) "artist combinations",
  count(distinct t.songid) "count"
from mytable t left join mytable tt
on tt.songid = t.songid and tt.artistid <> t.artistid
group by "artist combinations"
order by "count"
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/caVmxg56Uq1Jy8GeFQHfRE/1)
Results:

```
| artist combinations | count |
| ------------------- | ----- |
| 101 & 102           | 1     |
| 101 & 103           | 1     |
| 101 & 104           | 1     |
| 102 & 103           | 2     |
```

**Edit**:
This will also count when there are no common songs between artists:

```
select  
  min(t.artistid, tt.artistid) || ' & ' || 
  max(t.artistid, tt.artistid) "artist combinations",
  count(distinct t.songid) "count"
from mytable t inner join mytable tt
on tt.songid = t.songid and tt.artistid <> t.artistid
group by "artist combinations"
union all
select distinct
  min(t.artistid, tt.artistid) || ' & ' || 
  max(t.artistid, tt.artistid) "artist combinations",
  0 "count"
from mytable t inner join mytable tt
on tt.artistid <> t.artistid
and (select count(*) from(
  select songid from mytable where artistid = t.artistid
  intersect
  select songid from mytable where artistid = tt.artistid
  )) = 0
order by "count"
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/caVmxg56Uq1Jy8GeFQHfRE/4)
Results:

```
| artist combinations | count |
| ------------------- | ----- |
| 102 & 104           | 0     |
| 103 & 104           | 0     |
| 101 & 102           | 1     |
| 101 & 103           | 1     |
| 101 & 104           | 1     |
| 102 & 103           | 2     |
```

Comment: excellent, this works like a charm. THANK YOU! In the spirit of learning and not copying & pasting: could you help me also understand the code a bit and briefly comment what it is doing?

Comment: For each combination of 2 artists I keep one with min() and max() functions and then concatenate them. Then I group by this combination and count distinct songid.

Answer (score 0):

A few CTE's can help with generating all possible & existing artist combos.

Once you got both then you can left join the existing to the possible combos.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>  songID int not null, 
>  artistID int not null,
>  primary key (songID, artistID)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (songID, artistID) VALUES 
> (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103), 
> (2, 102), (2, 103), 
> (3, 101), (3, 104);
> ```

> ```
> WITH ARTISTS AS
> (
>   SELECT DISTINCT artistID
>   FROM mytable
> )
> , ARTISTCOMBOS AS
> (
>   SELECT a1.artistID AS artistID1, a2.artistID AS artistID2
>   FROM ARTISTS a1
>   JOIN ARTISTS a2 ON a2.artistID > a1.artistID
> )
> , SONGARTISTCOMBOS AS
> (
>    SELECT t1.artistID AS artistID1, t2.artistID AS artistID2, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.songID) AS TotalSongs
>    FROM mytable t1
>    JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.songID = t1.songID AND t2.artistID > t1.artistID
>    GROUP BY t1.artistID, t2.artistID
> )
> SELECT 
> a.artistID1 ||' & '|| a.artistID2 as "artist combinations", 
> COALESCE(sa.TotalSongs, 0) AS "Count"
> FROM ARTISTCOMBOS a
> LEFT JOIN SONGARTISTCOMBOS sa 
>   ON sa.artistID1 = a.artistID1 AND sa.artistID2 = a.artistID2
> ORDER BY a.artistID1, a.artistID2
> ```
>
> ```
> artist combinations | Count
> :------------------ | :----
> 101 & 102           | 1    
> 101 & 103           | 1    
> 101 & 104           | 1    
> 102 & 103           | 2    
> 102 & 104           | 0    
> 103 & 104           | 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=edc38707cee8820e4e4d0431bc4493c1)*

Answer (score 0):

welcome to sql and stackoverflow!

That following code will work, though would not give you zero collaborations. If you would need zeros, replace simple select with an outer join. Be careful to avoid double counting (that's why the < where statement). Use internal subquery to validate the results you want.

```
select aa.twoartists, count(aa.songID) from (
select CONCAT(CAST(a1.artistID as CHAR)," & ",CAST(a2.artistID as CHAR)) as twoartists, 
a1.artistID as artist1, a2.artistID as artist2, a1.songID    
from mytable a1, mytable a2
where a1.songID = a2.songID and a1.artistID < a2.artistID) aa
group by aa.twoartists;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one does the trick:

```
select artistid1, artistid2, sum(num) from (
  select s1.songid as songid1, s1.artistid as artistid1, s2.songid as songid2, s2.artistid as artistid2, 
        case when s1.songid = s2.songid then 1 else 0 end as num
  from mytable s1 cross join mytable s2
  where s1.artistid < s2.artistid)
group by artistid1, artistid2
order by artistid1;
```

P.S. I'm not familiar with sqlite syntax, but think this should work.